# How to update user and profile properly in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here I am trying to update user and user_profile model.This updates the user but the one problem with this is: If I don't provide the address or any other field then it becomes blank after updating.How can I solve this ?

If i update only one field then it makes other field null while updating.I want to store the user's previous data if user doesn't update the field

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='profile')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class UpdateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'profile']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.save()
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        instance.profile.address = profile_data.get('address', instance.profile.address)
        instance.profile.save()

        return instance
```

views.py

```
class UpdateUser(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UpdateUserSerializer
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
```

Comment: What do you mean by _update form_? You are not using forms in your code. It's api endpoint, you send PUT/PATCH request to change values and it will respond with updated `User` data.  Do you need to respond to GET requests as well?

Comment: @Gasanov  If i update only one field then it makes other field null while updating.I want to store the user's previous data if user doesn't update the field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overriding model instance fields on update with values from params. If there are no corresponding params, you will get empty strings as values.

DRF comes with this logic already implemented. You only have to process `profile` data. Change `serializers.py` to:

```py
class UpdateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'profile']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # We try to get profile data
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile', None)
        # If we have one
        if profile_data is not None:
            # We set address, assuming that you always set address
            # if you provide profile
            instance.profile.address = profile_data['address']
            # And save profile
            instance.profile.save()
        # Rest will be handled by DRF
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Make sure you use `PATCH` request, as `PUT` is for whole instance update. `PATCH` is for partial instance update.

Comment: why is that error `The `.update()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `users.serializers.UpdateUserSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.`

Comment: It's referring to [this feature](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers), but it shouldn't pop up with this code. I've updated code. It was because I accidentally got `profile` from `self.validated_data`.

Comment: It only updates the field which i provide for example initially there was both first_name and last_name but I only changed first_name.Now the first_name get updated but last_name became empty string

Comment: How can I use `PATCH` request.By default it is `PUT` request

Comment: Depends on how do you make requests. Are using jquery, postman, react/vue/angular, XMLhttpRequest?

Comment: i am using vue.Can we update full data also with `PATCH` request

Comment: Yes, if you provide full data. Here's doc on [`PATCH` request handling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin)